# How to get the directory tree of iPhone App Documents Directory

Tags: iphone

In my App, I created subfolders under Documents, and subfolders under subfolders. So there is a Document tree. I want to get the tree in a way that I am able to list them in a tableview. They will look like the following, linear listing with different indent to show their level.

[image]

I am not sure whether there is some convenient way to get this done or not, when I am trying to do it using while loop and for loop.

Appreciate your suggestions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple provides a number of classes for file system access, and even some for recursion that you're trying to do.

I suggest that you take a look at [the Apple File System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/Introduction/Introduction.html) and the [`NSFileManager` class documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Additionally, the [`NSDirectoryEnumerator` class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDirectoryEnumerator_Class/Reference/Reference.html) may help as well.

Comment: (NSArray *)subpathsAtPath:(NSString *)path   This is the one I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how to get entire hierarchy at a time. But following method can be helpful.

1 Use this to get documents derectory.

NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

2 use `- (NSArray *)contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:(NSString )path error:(NSError *)error`  for getting list of directories in document directory.

Read this Class refrence for more details.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html

3 Using following method you can make path of internal directory.

NSString *directoryPath = [documentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[MAIN_DIRECTORY stringByAppendingPathComponent:filePath]];

Using above three can together you can brows content of document directory.

Hope this is helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

and

```
NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *fileList = [manager directoryContentsAtPath:documentsDirectory];
    for (NSString *s in fileList){
       NSLog(s);
    }
```